# SELinuxの設定ファイルを編集後、ssh経由でログインできない

Tags: linux, centos, selinux

CentOSで次のファイルを編集して再起動しようとうしたら `ssh root` でログインできなくなりました、誰かご教授くださいませ!!

```conf
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#       targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#       strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted

setenforce 0
```

`# setenforce 0` に変更して `reboot` 打ってたらサーバーがすぐ終了して、 `ssh root` でログインできなくなりました。

Comment: 元々 `setenforce 0` が書かれていて、行頭に `#` を書き足してコメントアウトしたということでしょうか？またその理由は何でしょうか？

Comment: はい、もともとsetenforce 0 が書かれていて、行頭に # を書き足してコメントアウトしてreboot コマンドを打ちましたらサーバーが落ちて、ログインもできないです

Answer (score 1):

`setenforce 0` からコメントアウトしたのであれば SELinux が執行モードになっているのではないでしょうか。実際の端末かVPSなら管理コンソールからrootで入って`fixfiles relabel`を実行しないといけません。`setenforce 0`をコメントアウトする必要が無かったのであれば戻してから`fixfiles relabel`して下さい。
この辺りは失敗すると後戻り出来なくなる場合もあるのでドキュメントを見ながら作業して下さい。

Answer (score 0):

`SELINUX=enforcing` の状態で `setenforce 0` もコメントアウトしたのなら、SELinuxによってssh接続が制限されているのではないでしょうか。

端末のコンソールを操作できるなら、カーネルパラメータで一時的にSELinuxをPermissiveモード＝`setenforce 0`相当にすることができるようです。VPSなら管理画面からできるかもしれません。

[[Linux] SELinuxを無効にした後、Kernel panicになり起動できなくなった](http://www.ipentec.com/document/document.aspx?page=linux-boot-kernel-panic-after-selinux-disabled)

なぜ `SELINUX=disabled` でなく `setenforce 0` と書かれていたのか疑問ですが。。。

Comment: 変更してすぐ再起動したのが原因でした。
みなさんありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

まだ問題は残っているのでしょうか？
SELinuxは初めて有効にされたとき、ファイルにラベルという管理情報を書き込みます。
無効にして稼働していたものを有効に切り替えると最初のブートプロセスのなかでラベル付けするのでかなりの時間起動が止まっているように見えます。
少し（規模によりますが30分から1時間）くらい待てば使えるようになるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 変更前は `setenforce 0` されていたようなので、無効化されていたわけではないと思うのですが、どうでしょうか。（まともに使ったことがないので下手なことは言えないですが…）

Comment: 現状修正して正常に動いています。原因はreboot して5 分後にコンソールでサーバーを再起動したのが原因と思われます。どうか、rebootしてすぐサーバーを起動させるとインダーヒェスが削除されてしまうみたいです。